# res.sendFile() not sending file (no errors)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a simple login page using passport.js.

```
 $("#loginUser").on("click", function () {   //login button handler
            var User = {
                username: $('#username').val().trim().toLowerCase(),
                password: $("#password").val().trim()
            };
            //$("#password").val("");
            $.post("/login", User);
        });
```

The code for the post route for "/login" is below (taken from passport docs):

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/home/' + user.user_id);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

Below is the code for the "home" route:

```
  app.get("/home/:user?", function (req, res) { //home page
    console.log(req.params.user)
    if (req.user) {
      console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../public/home.html"))
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/home.html"), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('file sent!');
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("no user");
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/login.html"));
    }
  });
```

The issue I'm having is when the page is supposed to redirect to the home page, it just does nothing. The `console.log("file sent")` will trigger with no errors, even though nothing happens and the page stays on the login screen. However, if I physically type in localhost://8080/home the page will then load perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of your server not sending the file - it's a matter of your web page isn't redirecting properly.

Ajax calls which you are using with this code:

```
$.post("/login", User);
```

do not redirect automatically.  All they do is return the 302 response to your Ajax completion handler Javascript (which you don't have any code for).  So, your request is delivered to the server.  Your server sends a 302 redirect response, that 302 response comes back to your Javascript and gets dropped on the floor by your Javascript.

Only URLs put in the browser bar or URLS clicked on by the user or browser-only form posts (not done from Javascript) will redirect automatically.  Ajax calls do not redirect automatically - they just deliver the redirect status and location back to your Javascript where your Javascript has to then process it in order to do anything.

You have a couple of choices to fix:

1. Switch to a plain browser form post with no Javascript and then the browser itself will see and follow the redirect.
2. Use a completion handler for your Ajax call, check the status and if it's a 3xx response, then get the Location header and set `window.location = xxx` to the location in that header to cause the redirect to happen.

I haven't tested this, but here's the general concept for checking the status and manually redirecting based on a 3xx status.

```
$.post("/login", User).then((data, textStatus, jqXHR ) => {
    if (jqXHR.status >= 300 && jqXHR.status <= 399) {
       window.location = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Location");
    } else {
       console.log("not a redirect status of:", jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```